Does an Italian study visa allow me to fulfil an internship in Belgium?
I am an American Citizen with a Schengen student visa and I am studying in Italy but I am applying to an internship in Belgium. My studies require me to fulfill an internship for credit so this would be unpaid. I am questioning if I am allowed to live and work in Belgium under my current visa or if I need to apply for a new one?

To move from one EU country to another for more than 90 days, you will need a long-stay visa or a residence permit for that country.
Source: https://immigration-portal.ec.europa.eu/general-information/already-eu_en
